# how "document.createElement" works to "display" property

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

I found a interesting phenomenon and it performs different in Firefox from Chrome.

open you browser devTool with <kbd>F12</kbd> and type this.

```
var span=document.createElement("span");
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(span).display;
```

it returns "block" in Firefox and `""` in Chrome .
The first time I met the case was in Firefox and it amazed me that the result was "block"! However, when `document.body.appendChid(span)`,it was ok.

I searched in MDN but withot any harvest in the end.I guess the `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle` is influenced by the browser's rendering engine.The "display" property is set after that the element has rendered by the rendering engine to the DOM tree.And the gecko(Firefox) gives a default value to it as "block" while the webkit(Chrome) sets it "".

can anyone give a more detailed explaination?

Comment: Did you try at new `Tab`, `about:blank`? What are user agent styles of the `document`?

Comment: @guest271314 Thank you for your answer. <span> tag's display in user agent styles is nothing in Chrome, which means it is "inline".However in Firefox it's ”block" but I don't know where it is from since `display` is not a inherited css property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the spec does not specify whether elements outside the DOM have computed styles or not.

Firefox thinks they do. And they are affected by stylesheets in the document.

```js
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.createElement('span')).display);
// "flex" on Firefox
```

```css
span { display: flex; }
```

Chrome thinks they don't, so returns the empty string. You need to append them to the document in order to use `getComputedStyle`.

This was discussed in www-style: [computedStyle of cloneNode](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016May/0011.html)

You get `display: block` instead of the initial `inline` because, as dictated by [CSS Display](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#transformations),

> The root element’s display type is always [blockified](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#blockify).

When you create a `span` element outside the document, it has no parent, so it's a root. Then `inline` becomes `block`.

Similarly, if you had `span { display: inline-block }` in your stylesheet, you would also get `block`. With `span { display: inline-flex }` you would get `flex`, with `span { display: inline-table }` you would get `table`, and so on.

Comment: well,it clears some of my puzzle.Thank you. But where does the <span> tag's `display:block` come from?It's not in user agent style where I found nothing about span's `display` css property.And `display` is not a inherited css property.Is it `block` that is the default value of display property for the elements outside the DOM? @Oriol

Comment: @PageYe Good point, CSS Display blockifies root elements indeed.

Comment: sorry what is `blockify` ? it confused me.

Comment: @PageYe Blockification converts inline-level boxes to their block-level equivalent. `inline` and `inline-block` become `block`, `inline-flex` becomes `flex`, `inline-grid` becomes `grid`, `inline-table` becomes `table`, etc.